# Unable to find device in SDP mode

Tags: google-coral

I am trying to follow the guide from
https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board-micro/get-started/
but it fails at point 5. "*Try the face detection example*"
When I run the following script "python3 scripts/flashtool.py -e detect_faces" it fails with "**Encountered an error during flashing: Unable to find device in SDP mode.**"
Note I'm using Ubuntu via wsl2 in Windows 11 (using usbipd i powershell to attach the board usb with Ubuntu).
Here is the console output:

```
jal@UDV051:~/coralmicro$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 18d1:9308 Google Inc. Coral Dev Board Micro
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
jal@UDV051:~/coralmicro$ python3 scripts/flashtool.py -e detect_faces
Finding all necessary files
Creating Filesystem
        Section: 0x0
iMX bootable image generated successfully
Boot Section 0x00000000:
  FILL | adr=0x00010000 | len=0x00000004 | ptn=0xc2000105
  FILL | adr=0x00010004 | len=0x00000004 | ptn=0x00010020
  FILL | adr=0x00010008 | len=0x00000004 | ptn=0x00040004
  FILL | adr=0x0001000c | len=0x00000004 | ptn=0x00080004
  FILL | adr=0x00010020 | len=0x00000004 | ptn=0xc0010021
  ENA  | adr=0x00010000 | cnt=0x00000004 | flg=0x0110
  ERAS | adr=0x00000004 | cnt=0x00000004 | flg=0x0110
  ERAS | adr=0x00000008 | cnt=0x00000004 | flg=0x0110
  ERAS | adr=0x0000000c | cnt=0x00000040 | flg=0x0110
  LOAD | adr=0x00000004 | len=0x00017854 | crc=0xf4ffcd7e | flg=0x0110
  LOAD | adr=0x00000008 | len=0x00017854 | crc=0x38833290 | flg=0x0110
STATE_CHECK_FOR_ANY
STATE_CHECK_FOR_CORAL_MICRO
STATE_RESET_TO_SDP
STATE_CHECK_FOR_SDP
Encountered an error during flashing: Unable to find device in SDP mode.
```

Tried to run "python3 scripts/flashtool.py -e detect_faces" but it fails with "Encountered an error during flashing: Unable to find device in SDP mode."

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem with using Oracle VM VirtualBox to run Ubuntu 22.10.
I think the problem causing this has something to do with how the VM handles the USB Connection to the dev board.
As stated in the troubleshooting section under https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board-micro/get-started/ : "A computer is currently connected to the serial console via the board's USB port, which occupies the serial port line (`/dev/ttyACM`) that the flashtool needs, so the board does not receive the reset instruction."

I haven't figured out a solution, so I just set up Ubuntu natively on another computer I have. Now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://https:/https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board-micro/get-started/#flashing-stuck-at-state_check_for_sdp) the error appears when the flashtool fails to reset the device into Serial Downloader mode (aka Serial Download Protocol, or SDP).  [The solution](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board-micro/get-started/#serial-downloader) they offer:

> Start SDP mode in one of two ways:
>
> 1. Hold the User button while you press the Reset button.
> 2. Or, hold the User button while you plug in the USB cable.
>
> Release the button when the orange LED turns on.
>
> Then try flashing the board again with working code.

#1 worked for me